# focus should be work inside a particular area once I click over the tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

focus should be work inside a particular area once I click over the tab I achieve this using this approach is there any other approach please let me know.

URL :- https://jrf29f.csb.app/

Thanks in advance

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";
import { data, buttonPositions } from "./data";

export default function Drawer() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState("");
  const drawerRef = useRef(null);
  const btnRef = useRef(null);
  const focusableAreaRef = useRef(null);

  const handleOpen = (event, pos) => {
    btnRef.current = event.target;
    // console.log(event.target);
    setIsOpen(true);
    setPosition(pos);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    if (btnRef.current) {
      btnRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen && drawerRef.current) {
      drawerRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Escape") {
        handleClose();
      }
      // console.log(event.key);
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);


  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Tab") {
      const focusableEls = focusableAreaRef.current.querySelectorAll(
        'a, input, button, select, textarea, [tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"])'
      );

      const [firstFocusableEl, lastFocusableEl] = [
        focusableEls[0],
        focusableEls[focusableEls.length - 1]
      ];

      if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableEl) {
        event.preventDefault();
        firstFocusableEl.focus();
      }
    }
  };

  const drawerClass = {
    left: "drawerX",
    right: "drawerX",
    top: "drawerY",
    bottom: "drawerY"
  }[position];

  return (
    <>
      {buttonPositions.map((position) => (
        <button
          key={position}
          className={position}
          onClick={(event) => handleOpen(event, position)}
          aria-label={`Open ${position} Drawer`}
        >
          Open {position} Drawer
        </button>
      ))}
      {isOpen && (
        <div
          ref={focusableAreaRef}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          className={`${drawerClass} ${position}`}
          aria-labelledby="drawer-header"
        >
          <div className="drawer-header" id="drawer-header">
            <h2>Drawer Content</h2>
            <button
              ref={drawerRef}
              className="close-icon"
              onClick={handleClose}
              aria-label="Close Drawer"
              tabIndex="0"
            >
              <AiOutlineClose />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="drawer-icons">
            {data.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <a href="#" key={index}>
                  {item.icon} <span>{item.linkName}</span>
                </a>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes this approach is good for keyboard navigation. If you want more accessible further you can add keyboard arrow keys navigations as well.

Comment: @Dakshank I want reduce line of code is there any way.